# О переводах Толкиена

Tags: переводы

Знаю, что на эту тему защищено много диссертаций, но все-таки.
Есть много разных переводов "Властелина Колец", и в разных переводах фамилию Фродо  переводят по-разному: где-то Беггинс, где-то Торбинс. А Гоблин (он же Дмитрий Пучков) вообще в своем знаменитом переводе использовал вариант Сумкин.
При этом я считаю, что Гоблин в своем переводе сделал правильнее всего: если уж переводишь фамилию на русский, то какой смысл оставлять английское окончание?
Как вы думаете, правильно ли сделали переводчики, переведя корень фамилии, но оставив английское окончание? Или все-таки прав Гоблин?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если
 напрямую выполнять пожелание Толкина, то Дмитрий Пучков абсолютно прав.
 Автор "Властелина колец" хотел чтобы его "говорящие" фамилии 
переводили.

Но тут возникает проблема восприятия. Мы привыкли, что 
персонажи фэнтези и рыцарских легенд носят европейские имена. Славянские
 фамилии в таком контексте будут с точки зрения русского человека 
смотреться нелепо. По этой причине при локализации компьтерных игр в 
стиле "фэнтези" имена, которые в оригинале славянские при переводе, зачастую, 
становятся западноевропейскими. Этот момент и учитывал переводчик 
называя главного героя Торбинсом.

Думаю наиболее точным вариантом в наше время, стали бы варианты "Торбин"
 и "Сумкинс", делать, вслед за Гоблином, из Фродо русского паренька, 
по-моему не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Любая попытка "перевести" смысловую нагрузку фамилии будет извращением замысла автора, потому что мыслить, как автор, переводчики не могут!

Иногда, переводя непонятные названия, придуманные автором, можно в корне изменить их смысл!

Можно и нужно переводить прозвища, потому что они дают характеристику персонажа! Но переводить фамилии — это полный бред!

Comment: Вы можете исправлять свой ответ и добавлять в него информацию, пользуясь функцией "править"